# Attribute error when trying to get number of nodes

Tags: python, networkx

I'm making a graph on python with networkx. I define g as Board(4). When I try and print `g.number_of_nodes()`, however, I get an attribute error, I don't know why this is.

```
def Board(n):
    board=nx.Graph()
    for i in range(0,n):
        for j in range(0,n):
            board.add_node((i,j))
        nx.draw(board)
    pyl.show()

g= Board(4)
print g.number_of_nodes()
```

Any help would be much appreciated,

Jack

Comment: What are you expecting `g` to be? You don't return anything from the Board function.

Comment: I'm quite new to Python and networkx. I want g to be the graph produced by Board(4).

Comment: Should I delete nx.draw(board) and pyl.show() and write return(board)?

Comment: Please try to add `return board` at end of your function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your Board function doesnt return anything...

```
g= Board(4) 
print g.number_of_nodes()
```

in this case g equals None...
you have to return something, in this case variable named *board*

```
def Board(n):
    board=nx.Graph()
    for i in range(0,n):
        for j in range(0,n):
            board.add_node((i,j))
        nx.draw(board)
    pyl.show()
    return board
```